# How do data centers deal with constant disk failure?

Tags: hard-drive, datacenter

According to disk reliability report on 2022

https://www.techspot.com/news/97909-ssd-reliability-only-slightly-better-than-hdd-backblaze.html

[image: Q3 2023 spinning drive failures]

SSD hard drives have a annualized failure rate of 0.98% , HDD have 1.6%.

This means if you have a data center of 600 disk:

There is a `(1-0.01)^600 = 0.2% that no disk will fail for the year`. If disk failure distribution is uniform, does this mean that there is one disk failure per day?

If there is 1000 disk in data center:

`(1- 0.016 )^1000 = 0.0000000009`, this means every two seconds, there is a disk failure.

I must be calculating something wrong.

1. If the math is right, how do gcp, AWS handle disk replacement every couple second?
2. If the math is wrong, what am I missing?

Comment: Regardless of your math, how regular (large) enterprises deal with failed disks is usually still by replacing them when needed. With still 1000's of our own servers and many ceph nodes with 24 disks  that means that for our datacenter teams replacing failed disks is a daily recurring part of their jobs. - Hyperscalers may obviously take different approaches on how to deal with hardware failures because their economics are different.

Comment: even on a 24 shelf, it could happen one week, that you replace 4 drives, it would also happen that you did not change a drive for a year. And yes, replacing faulty drives are a daily routine check, and if happens, i called dell for a replacement, within 4 hours i got my restock

Comment: The provider that you referenced, Backblaze, has 260,000 disks. 935 failed over a 180 day period. That is five failures per day.

Answer (score 6):

Your math is wrong

`(1-0.016)^1000` is the probability that you will make it through a whole year without a single drive failure (with a pool of 1000 disks), but you don't just multiply 1 year by that figure to get the amount of time it takes for a disk to fail, that makes no sense.

If the AFR is 1.6%, that means 16 of your 1000 disks will fail over the course of one year, or roughly every 22 days (not accounting for the possibility of the replacement drives also failing)

Here's another way to work it out, with 1.6% chance of a drive failing in 1 year, on average it should take `1/0.016 = 62.5` years for a single particular drive to fail, so every 62.5 years of cumulative drive-years you'd expect one failure. Distributed over 1000 drives you'd go through 62.5 drive-years in `62.5/1000 = 0.0625` years real time, or 22.8 days.

Answer (score 0):

There are robots available where you can put in 100s of disk and the robot automatically replaces a failed disk

*Alibaba then claimed to have developed a better version in the form of Tianxun, an AI powered robot that can replace faulty hard drives.*
https://analyticsindiamag.com/current-state-of-robots-at-the-data-centers/

---

Some hyperscale datacenters also use containers where everything is in, and where a certain amount of hardware can fail, when it goes over that they just forklift the container out and forklift a new container in. When your hard drives fail, it’s nearly always because of vibration issues. A cloud data center runs in systems so carefully designed that the main reason for failure is humidity.